# Access PSObject Properties Values

Tags: powershell

I have a `PSObject` that looks like this:

```
IsGettable      : True
Value           : {@{friority=Medium;removedDate=;etc..}
```

What I want to do is extract the `friority` that are `medium` and get a *count* of them.

I've tried a couple of different things using `select-object` and `get-member` with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

So, as suggested I converted the object into a `JSON` object and wrote it to the file.

```
{
    "data":  [
                 {
                     "id":  487777,
                     "proVersion":  null,
                     "proName":  null,
                     "revision":  0,
                     "folderId":  4555,
                     "friority":  "Medium"}],
    "count":  567,
    "responseCode":  200
}
```

To save space I have removed some of the values of the object.

I have since changed the suggested solution to below:

```
($projIssues | Where-Object { $_.data.friority -eq "Medium" })
```

Now, If I add `.count` I am receiving the count value of the object

> 567

Comment: If you provide a Json representation of your object / objects we may be able to help without __having to guess__

Comment: A quick guess: `($objects | Where { $_.Value.friority -eq 'Medium' }).Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off,  Thanks to **Santiago** and **mklement0** for the help.

I ended up using this statement:

```
$issues = $projIssues.data.friority | WHERE { $_ -eq "Medium"}
```

then checking the `count` like so:

```
$issues.count
```